Why is Database user in disabled state (member of a login group)?
Under the logins I have added a security group containing 5 users.
Then, I added one of these users into the database as a database user (db_datareader permission)
But against the user I can see a red cross mark.
I suppose SQL is trying to tell me that the user is disabled? But I can't find a way to enable it.

Most likely the user doesn't have connect permissions to the database. I can see three ways for that to happen. I just tried all three of these.

You do it explicitly: REVOKE (or DENY) CONNECT TO "DOMAIN\USERNAME"
The group is added to the database, but the group has a user in the database with DENY CONNECT privileges to the database: DENY CONNECT TO "DOMAIN\GROUPNAME"
The public group in the database has DENY connect to the database

In any case, my suspicion is that it is the CONNECT permission that is lacking.
(FWIW you can't disable the login for a windows group. You can DENY, but that doesn't make a red cross in SSMS. Nor do you get a red cross if the account is disabled at the OS level. I just tested those,)
